# I'm writing a for loop with an if statement inside it but it returns nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to find if there are shared elements in two different arrays, and I wrote the following code, but it returns nothing.

```
    gradelist1 = [1, 3, 5]
    gradelist2 = [1 ,4,7]
    for value in (gradelist1, gradelist2):
        if value in gradelist1 and value in gradelist2:
            print('The value occurs in both the lists')
            break
```

Comment: Did you run your code? If yes what is the output?

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating over the lists, not over the values in the lists. Also there is no need to iterate over both lists at once.

```
gradelist1 = [1, 3, 5]
gradelist2 = [1 ,4,7]
for value in gradelist1:
   if value in gradelist2:
        print('The value occurs in both the lists')
        break
```

You can also just do list comprehension `[i for i in gradelist1 if i in gradelist2]` to get all the values that are in both lists directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way

```
gradelist1 = [1, 3, 5]
gradelist2 = [1, 4, 7]
x = [] # create a list
for value in (gradelist1):
    if value in gradelist2: #first check if the value from the list1 is in the list 2
      x.append(value) # add to it the values if the condition is rigth

print('the folloging numbers are inclued in both arrays')
print(x)
```

Comment: You do `for value in gradelist1:` and in the first line of the loop you ask  `if value in gradelist1`. How do you expect the current value to be removed from the list between those statements?

Answer (score -1):

**Your code should look like this:**

```
 gradelist1 = [1, 3, 5]
 gradelist2 = [1 ,4,7]
 for value1,value2 in zip(gradelist1, gradelist2):
        if value1 in gradelist1 and value2 in gradelist2:
            print('The value occurs in both the lists')
            break
```

Comment: This code will not run because `for value1,value2 in (gradelist1, gradelist2)` will raise an error. It also will always evaluate `True` because you're checking the list the value is originally from.